# Can't add existing Virtual Network to Virtual network gateway in Azure

Tags: azure, networking, vpn, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

While creating the Virtual network gateway and selecting the vnet, it says the VNet is "in use".

VNET address space is 10.0.0.0/16

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

[image]

I created a new subnet and it has no devices connected to it.

[image]

The connected devices are not on `GatewaySubnet`.

[image]

Comment: Hello @john did your problem got resolved ?

Answer (score -1):

I reproduce your scenario and it is working fine for me.

[image]

[image]

**Below Point Should be notice before creating VNET Gateway**

**Gateway subnet address range**: This field only appears if your VNet doesn't have a gateway subnet. It's best to specify /27 or larger (/26,/25 etc.).

Please check the same for Gateway Subnet address range from this MS doc: [Tutorial - Create and manage a VPN gateway: Azure portal - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-create-gateway-portal)